# I'm looking for a data set of food stuffs and/or recipe ingredients

Tags: data-request, food

I'm looking for a list of ingredients to pull from for an app. I've used data sets from fitness and calorie counting apps but one larger cleaner one without a meal would be great.

All I need are the names of the dishes, no other information.

Comment: Are the answers here helpful? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3757/1511

Comment: List of ingredients AND dishes, if I understand correctly?