# Where can I get a food ingredient database or API

Tags: api, database, food

I'm currently working on a project that requires the use of an ingredients database or API. In my app I have some strings and I want to know if that string is belongs to an ingredient name. I'm just wondering if there are any free database and APIs that can help me achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4078/1511 or https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3757/1511

Comment: I'd start with googling for a recipes database.

Answer (score 1):

Just by chance, there is an article on ProgrammableWeb about the
  [10 Most Popular Food APIs](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/10-most-popular-food-apis/brief/2019/08/06), maybe number 2 on their list, [Edamam Food Database API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/edamam-food-database) gives you what you need: [api page](https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs)