# Where can I find a downloadable grocery store food ingredient database / data set?

Tags: data-request, food

I'm looking for a downloadable ingredient database / data set.  I'd like to be able to write my own query to the data set, eliminating potentially harmful ingredients to see what would be potentially healthy to eat.

Does such a downloadable data set / database exist?  The closest I've been able to find is [foodfacts.com](http://www.foodfacts.com/ci/nutritionsearch/Brads%20Raw) and it's not an open data set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of common foodstuffs/meals?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/list-of-common-foodstuffs-meals)

Comment: I'm no specialist, but calling them duplicates seems correct. If that's the case, maybe the word "ingredient" should be added to the title of the other, as that does seem like a reason someone might accidentally overlook it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried [Open Food Facts](http://openfoodfacts.org/)? It's a "free, open and collaborative database of food products from the entire world."  The data is [offered under the Open Database License](http://world.openfoodfacts.org/terms-of-use)